# Jquery error handling globally when code refactor requires hiding sections of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been tasked with Hiding entire blocks of html code from basic users

Thus only an Admin in the role of this asp.net MVC application with razor view engine is allowed to even View specific sections of the HTML

Once I did the part of introducing quick changes with mvc razor blocks in which thing are blocked I end up with many many many of these problems in which the person who wrote this didn't do any defensive programming.

**Example**

```
  if ($("#GateCodes_GateResponsibleParty").val().split("~")[0] == "Other") { 
    ....  
  }
```

Well, that blows up since I am not allowing a lot of sections to be seen.

1. I need to fix things like **split**
2. Can I have more of a global replace or a way for the jquery / javascript to not freak out if not found?

**strong text**

Comment: `if($("#GateCodes_GateResponsibleParty").length>0){ //do things with the element }` , at least, that's what I do when I know an element my not always exist and calling a function on it if `undefined` will cause an error. Stuff like initializing plugins

Comment: True,  just so many of those inputs ....  i'm wondering if i should instead make entire divs hidden , then that code still works...

Comment: That depends, how much do you trust your end users? If one of them goes into inspect element and unhides the inputs, will they be able to do / submit/ change something they shouldnt be able to? Honestly such a setup should authenticate users on the server side before allowing them to make changes to protected data. If these concerns are alleviated with your application logic, hiding the divs should be sufficient.

Comment: Then again, its generally a good idea to not expose application logic to users who dont have access to the features the logic applies to. For example, a malicious user could learn how the administrative portion of your application works by inspecting the HTML forms and javascript ajax calls and use that knowledge to attempt to do malicious things with or to your application. Of course, this is always a risk to some degree. It's all about levels of trust.

Comment: Yes,  very good points.   It happens to be intranet internal users of which the application information is not too sensitive but I need to look at the source etc..  thx